# Как из Debian работать с файлами в папке Windows?

Tags: debian, samba

В локальной сети нужно из сервера на Debian открыть папку под Windows по пути **\server\!integration1c-telegram$**.

Через самбу удалось достучаться по пути **smb://192.168.64.12/!integration1c-telegram$/**

Но не могу понять, как с этим путем работать в Debian? Нужно, например, копировать оттуда файлы и т.п.

Что-то типа такого:

```
ls smb://192.168.64.12/!integration1c-telegram$/
```

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант рабочего стола**

Установи `gvfs-fuse` подключенные папки будут в `/run/user/1000/gvfs` (может отличаться в версиях, но увидишь в mount)

```
$ ls $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs/
'smb-share:server=192.168.0.3,share=обмен'
$ ls $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs/*/
 IT   PDF   Архив   Бухгалтерия
```

**Вариант для консоли и скриптов**

Монтируй через mount

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/shara
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=$USER //192.168.1.104/shara /mnt/shara
```

или через fstab.

Comment: ls $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs/*/: ls: невозможно получить доступ к /run/user/1000/gvfs/*/: Нет такого файла или каталога

Comment: что-то, наверное, я не так делаю

Comment: перезагрузись) fuse не видит те подключения, которые были до его установки.

Папка gvfs может быть в другом месте, если Дебиан Jessie и более древний. посмотри `$HOME/.gvfs/`

Comment: перезагрузился, ls $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR$HOME/.gvfs/*/: ls: невозможно получить доступ к /run/user/1000/home/sergey/.gvfs/*/: Нет такого файла или каталога

Comment: а вы читали мой коммент или наугад слепили 2 переменных?

Comment: `mount` посмотрите